# Creating TcpStream within async block fails due to return error?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/runtime/index.html) for `tokio::runtime::Runtime` and trying to adapt it to create a TcpStream that serves as a client to a remote server. I'd like to have the support of a thread pool because my applications may have hundreds of clients each connecting to a remote server.

The problem is when I adapt the example to use TcpStream instead of a TcpListener, it seems to have a problem with the return type:

```
let runtime = runtime::Builder::new().threaded_scheduler().build()?;
let ret = runtime.block_on(async {
    let mut listener = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;
});
```

It fails with the error:

> the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that returns
>   `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
>   the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()` required by
>   `std::ops::Try::from_error`rustc(E0277)

I believe this comes from `.await?` which is used with `bind()` and `accept()`. So is the example outdated or am I missing something with `accept()`?

Comment: No, I'm more trying to understand the semantics of `block_on` than `?`.

Answer (score 0):

The method where this code is called from should return `Result<TcpStream, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`. I had io::Error instead.